# Video Effects for iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to add a Dot Matrix or a Vignette overlay to a number of images.

Should this be done on each individual image or can it be added to the video as an overlay effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework. As the name suggests it uses GPU to blend effects to video (each frame). You can apply effects live during playback or you can preprocess the video and play it from file.

Comment: Yes, it will do any video processing you wish. You will need to take some time to understand it, but it's basically easy. Be sure to check example apps.

Comment: Great thanks. So just to make sure before I dig in, can it handle applying these effects to a complete video file (writing the effects into the video data)

Comment: @Helium3 - Look at the SimpleVideoFileFilter example, which does just this. I should warn that there might be a slight bug with the audio recording in certain cases, which I'm looking into.

Comment: @BradLarson - Ok will watch out for the audio bug thanks. Thanks for making the framework available.